# Can the Safari 6 omnibar search be changed from google.com to google.co.uk?

Tags: macos, safari, search-engine

How can I change it so when I search using the omnibar it searches google.co.uk and not google.com.

For example when I want to look at prices for a product, I use the omnibar to search google but it shows me prices in dollars as it is looking results in google.com.

I would like to show results from google.co.uk to get localized search for the UK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just delete all your google.com cookies (not the google.co.uk ones) and it will magically start working! See http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=1157369

Comment: Brilliant! This worked.

Answer (score 1):

I installed a extension, called [Keysearch](http://www.macosxtips.co.uk/keysearch/). So that you can config some keywork to do the search. Fo example, you can config a keywork 'gguk' for google.co.uk, and in the ominibar, you can use gguk plus what you want to search.

[image]

Comment: I don't like using extensions for stuff like this, is there not a way to do this natively?

Answer (score 1):

[Glims](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/27708/glims) will let you define any search engine as the default, along with many other great features  :)

It is not an extension, but a plugin. Agreed, this is not as good as native, but is a one-time install with much less runtime overhead than extensions.