# How to remove suggestion from Safari omnibar

Tags: macos, safari, monterey

When I type `maps.go` into the omnibar it suggests and selects `maps.google.co.jp`

I would prefer it to select maps.google.com

My history does not contain any `maps.google.co.jp` or `google.co.jp` entries.

How can I stop safari from suggesting it?

---

[Can the Safari 6 omnibar search be changed from google.com to google.co.uk?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/62736/can-the-safari-6-omnibar-search-be-changed-from-google-com-to-google-co-uk) is not a duplicate because that question is about using the omnibar to search, not using the omnibar to visit a website. I just tried deleting my Google cookies and it didn't work.

Comment: I just tried: After removing the full history and restarting Safari, it stopped to autocomplete "maps.go". If this didn't help in your case: Do you have a bookmark pointing to maps.google.co.jp? Or are you located in Japan?

Comment: @nohillside I only removed all cookies that contain the word 'google'. I also only deleted all google.co.jp history entries, not my entire history. No bookmark and I'm not in japan.

Comment: You might not have found all history entries, why not try with a full deletion?

Comment: @nohillside it would make me sad and inconvenient to delete my entire history. How could searching "google.co.jp" not have found all history entries? How can I find all history entries causing this problem?